# can't send email to google from webmail cpanel

Tags: cpanel, webmail

I use my host for webmail. I can send email to yahoo and other webmail, but I can't send to Gmail or google app.
error:

```
Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
tinhphaistc@gmail.com
    SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
    host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.129.26]:
    550-5.7.1 [103.3.245.71       1] Our system has detected an unusual rate of
    550-5.7.1 unsolicited mail originating from your IP address. To protect our
    550-5.7.1 users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has been blocked.
    550-5.7.1 Please visit http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html to review
    550 5.7.1 our Bulk Email Senders Guidelines. hb2si3576957pac.234 - gsmtp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server must be on blacklist and Google is rejecting emails from your IP. Simple fix is Change IP :(  and make sure your CMS (Joomla, or wordpress usually) is patched and up to date.

Answer (score 0):

according to mail headers it seems that bulk mails had sent from your server due to this your IP has blocked in gmail. If you are sending bulk mails then go through [Bulk Senders Guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126) or if you are not sending bulk mails then check if spam mails had sent from your server.